# How to catch client request on bluetooth server side "read characteristic value"?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, gatt

Bluetooth module on client side allows to receive indications and notifications when "characteristic value" is changed. It requires to make configuration changes using UUID: 2902 (the Client Characteristic Configuration).

Is it possible on server side to catch client request "read characteristic value"? I want to update requested characteristic before client will get its value.

Comment: On iOS side (since it's tagged Core-Bluetooth which is iOS) and if the device is an iOS one, it's possible, it should trigger that method: "`peripheralManager:didReceiveReadRequest:` Invoked when a local peripheral device receives an Attribute Protocol (ATT) read request for a characteristic that has a dynamic value."

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible for most of the devices.
On the single devices, you need refer the verdor's code, you at least can access the code level of ATT/GATT.
On Android, you may handle it under `onCharacteristicWriteRequest`.